# New Google API Key "Google Maps API v3" doesn't work for Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I am working with the Google Places API (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search), and have generated a new Google API Key with 'Any IP Allowed'. When I try to get the results of the API service URLs below, I am getting a REQUEST DENIED error.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA3vtFM8AMlIO853ra82KzryBs752VIWts

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?key=AIzaSyA3vtFM8AMlIO853ra82KzryBs752VIWts&location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1000&sensor=false

I have tried all combinations of the request parameters, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

You must also activate the places-service in the API-console.

Comment: Correct, the Maps API Key is for the JavaScript Maps API and will work with the Places Library in the Maps API. A separate key is necessary for the Places Webservice API

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [Authentication](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#Authentication) instructions on the Places API Documentation getting started page to activate the Places API Web Service for your APIs Console Key.